# use different java version to run two programs

Tags: centos, java, jdk

I installed two JAVA JREs on my new CentOS since Cassandra needs java7u25 or later while iReport needs to work with 1.6.

Now how do I launch each program from command line telling each program which version to use?

Do I have to change the `/etc/profile` file? If so how?

Comment: I don't have Java installed...but have you tried (if you have both versions of Java installed) you can probably run them like `Java6 path/to/iReport` and `Java7 path/to/Cassandra` or specifying a full path to Java executable `/path/to/Java`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no point in having them both in [`$PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) because only one will get used.  You could symlink one to a different name -- e.g. `java6` -- I've never tried this w/ java and not sure if it would work.

The best way to do this would be to install one of them (presumably 1.6) in a location like `/opt/java6`, leaving 1.7 as the default.  Then when you want to use 6:

```
export PATH=/opt/java6/bin:$PATH
```

And start it from the command line.  You could also put all that together in a script.  Don't try to run Cassandra from the same shell after that unless you remove that from `$PATH` (easy way to check is `echo $PATH`).

To automate this for one specific application:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=/opt/java6/bin:$PATH
exec /path/to/application
```

You can then put that somewhere in the regular `$PATH` (e.g., `/usr/local/bin`), make sure it is executable (`chmod 755 whatever.sh`) and start the application that way.  It will then not affect `$PATH` in the process which launches it.

Comment: I don't see why you'd have to open the third shell.  You just want to change the path in the second one (via `export`) then start iReport. Using two separate tabs in a GUI terminal will work for this.  I've edited in what I meant by "putting this in a script", if you want to do that.

Comment: RHEL8 recommends `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk yourprogram` but I am having difficulty with it on Debian.

Comment: I know the default java can be changed with `update-alternatives --config java` but you would need to change this every time you switch between applications. The basic "java" command just symlinks to one of the versions in /usr/libs/jvm... if you were given java source rather than pre-compiled bytecode you also may need to change `javac` which compiles java.

Answer (score 1):

This works both launching from a terminal emulator and from a desktop icon launcher for a program I have that will not run on with my default openJRE-11. Using Debian-10 buster with XFCE

`/bin/sh -c 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH /home/username/myapplication'`
Might also try: 
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH /home/username/myapplication`

Also you could make an alias for each java version so that something short like j8o = `/bin/sh -c 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH` and the final everyday command would be `j8o ./myapplication`

To change the default java `update-alternatives --config java` then follow the prompt. The same can be used for setting the default for javac (the bytecode compiler) if needed. May need sudo to change the default.